# Control anchor property not working when form starts maximized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here's my problem: I have a winform with controls on it. Many of these controls have their Anchor property set to Top|Right. The size of the form in the designer is set to 1680x1050. If my resolution is set to 1680x1050 then it always comes up correctly.

If I change to a smaller resolution(say 1600x900) and the form is set to open as Maximized, then none of my controls move themselves to maintain their distance from the right edge. The controls on the right edge are all sticking out off the form a little. But, if I then unmaximize the window, and I can resize the window and all the controls will maintain their **current, incorrect** distance from the right edge.

If I set the form to start as normal(not maximized) then it opens up with all the controls in the right place, and everything stays in the right place if I resize the form.

This has been a very frustrating problem. Do any of you kind souls have advice for me?

Comment: Do you get this same behavior when you programmatically change the form to maxed when it loads via: theForminquestion.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; during the Load event on the form?

Comment: Just checked, and no, if I maximize during the Load event everything comes up correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id recommend just using my proposed solution of:

```
 theForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

My guess is that the property "Maximized" that is set during the initialization call of the form and may be causing the problems. (It's hard to say without seeing the project code). The Load even gets called after some of the more important events, so if there is some sort of existing problem with that property, it is avoided using the FormWindowState.Maximized code.

If you wish to post the actual code of what you think may be causing the problems, I'll edit this answer to help.

-J

Comment: This works as a workaround for now, but I'd like to know why this is happening, since the anchors work as expected on some other forms in the same app. If I find out more I'll let you know.

Comment: One thing you could try is take the form itself, cut everything out of it (Ctrl + x), insert a panel and change that panels Dock property to Fill. Then paste everything back into that panel. (No other changes needed).

This would cause your controls to be anchored to the panel (aka the parent container) instead of the form, thus fixing the problem if the problem stems from anchoring to the form.

Let me know if that has any affect.

Comment: Just tried to put together a minimal code reproduction and it looks like a 3rd party control is somehow responsible, since this bad behavior only happens when the 3rd party control is on the form. I'll send a message to them and see what's up.

Comment: The diagnostic here is that this 3rd party control causes the form's native window to be created too early, before the constructor is completed. Override OnHandleCreated and set a breakpoint on it. Look at the call stack to find the property assignment that triggers this.

Comment: Followed your advice and OnHandleCreated is triggered by this line:    `( (System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)( this.waveformGraph ) ).EndInit();`

Comment: 3rd party [confirms](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-NET/Possible-bug-in-AxCWGraph/td-p/1700368) that this is a bug in their control. They recommended the same workaround you did. :)

Comment: For posterity sake, the problem here is caused because the Handle of the control is created while SuspendLayout is in effect. Since in this case it is caused by the EndInit of standard-offending 3rd party code, another option may be to move that EndInit line below the ResumeLayout line.

Answer (score 0):

I Solve my problem by:

Set the Control AutoSize property to false.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoSize = false; //true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all controls in SplitContainer and set Dock property of splitcontainer and control such as datagridview = Fill