# Anchor of Control in SplitPanel not working with User Settings

Tags: .net, winforms, anchor, splitpanel

In a .NET 4.0 Windows Forms application, I have a `SplitPanel` with a multi-line `TextBox` (with `Anchor` set to`Top, Bottom, Left, Right`) in its first panel. Distance to each border are maintained perfectly if I move the splitter in either the Designer or running application.

The [`SplitterDistance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterdistance.aspx) property is bound to a user scope setting.

However, this does not work if the `SplitterDistance`'s value is modified independently and the application is restarted or the designer is reloaded. The distance in question is wrong on reload or startup, but it is kept equally wrong over further resize operations (as it should with this `Anchor` basically).

I guess this may have something to do with the initialization sequence order in Windows Forms. I found sort of a related issue on SO as well: [Control anchor property not working when form starts maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364823/control-anchor-property-not-working-when-form-starts-maximized).

Does anybody know an elegant way to handle this behaviour?

Comment: Pretty unclear, "the user setting value", what is stored in it?

Comment: Thanks, Hans, totally forgot that. Added another short paragraph.

Comment: Restore the value in the form's Load event, after all resizing and layout is completed.